# empty array when nesting callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I'm looping over an array of JSON data returned from couchdb, and added the data to an array then returning the array, The array should contain the rows from couchdb but `[]` is returned.

```
var Album = {
  all: function() {
    var data, albums = [];
    request({ uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/_all_docs'}, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw error;
        data = JSON.parse(body);
        data.rows.forEach(function(d) {
            request({ uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/' + d.id }, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) throw error;
                albums.push(JSON.parse(body));  
            });
        });
    });
    return albums;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` *will* be returned initially, although once the callback executes the array will contain the necessary data. That's the nature of node's callbacks - they are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what davin said, you normally handle asynchronous operations with callbacks.  The problem with your code is that if you have *n* different albums, you have *n* different request operations happening **simultaneously** but you have no way of knowing when they **all** finish.

I'm not a Node.js guy, so maybe there are utilities to handle this, but with vanilla javascript, here's how I would handle such a thing with minimal changes to your code.

#### Here's some pseudo-javascript for brevity

```
Album.all = function(callback){
    request( "_all_docs", function(albums){
        var albumsLeft = albums.length;
        var results = [];
        albums.forEach( function(album_id){
            request( "albums/" + album_id, function(album){
                results.push(album);
                albumsLeft -= 1;                
                if( albumsLeft === 0){
                    callback(results);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```